# I have errors for unresolved symbols but i have checked the references and they exist

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, c++11, linker-errors

**What i am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to build a project without any errors

**What is happening?**

I am getting unresolved errors

However i have checked that the lib file is referenced correctly and it is.

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project Project Rank    Path    File    Line    
 Column Category    Suppression State   Tool
  Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 
 osdp_hub::osdp_hub(void)" (??0osdp_hub@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function 
 "private: static void * __cdecl dcp_core::core::thread(void *)" (?
  thread@core@dcp_core@@CAPAXPAX@Z) libdcp  6   
  C:\Users\Stephen\source\repos\OldSensurityConfigurationTool\halo_dcp  
  C:\Users\Stephen\source\repos\OldSensurityConfigurationTool\halo_dcp\core.obj 1   1           Link
```

**What i expected to happen**

the project to build without errors

code causing error

this code is being referenced in one project
    osdp_hub *hub = create_osdp_hub();

this code is being is the code that is being referenced from the project above

```
 #ifdef SHARED_LIB_BUILD
 std::ofstream hub_logfile;
 int32_t hub_logcount = OSDP_LOG_FILE_DEPTH;

 osdp_hub* create_osdp_hub() {
    return new osdp_hub();
}

void destroy_osdp_hub( osdp_hub* p ) {
if ( p ) {
    p->m_thread_sem->wait();
    *p->m_thread_running = 2;
    p->m_thread_sem->post();

    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        utilities::millisleep( 100 );

    p->m_thread_sem->wait();
        running = *p->m_thread_running == 2;
        p->m_thread_sem->post();
    }
    delete p;
}
   p = 0;
}
#endif
```

additional info

i have removed and readded references
changed target machine to the same in this project and projects it depends on
checked the bin folders for the actual file.
Testing builds in x64 and x86

Comment: i would post entire code, but its huge

Comment: are you mixing c and c++?

Comment: actually it looks like you are defining the code in a header file, why are you doing that?

Comment: im following the standards of the guy who was working on this before me

Comment: MCVEs are not restricted to source code; in this case, the code itself doesn't tell us much, not only because it's incomplete but mainly because the problem is apparently with the way the Visual Studio project files (*.vcxproj) describe the various compiler and linker invocations.

Comment: inside of    osdp_hub* create_osdp_hub() {
      return new osdp_hub();
} i can use osdp_hub*  hub = nullptr, then access the methods from their. is this an acceptable way to do this?

Comment: found the answer. There are 6 build configurations, for some reason this library only builds in one of them. So am going to fix this